# {props.props.title}? Why not {props.title}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

I am still learning how to use API data with react and nextjs. But, why does my function only work when I write `{props.props.title}` instead of, what I would expect, `{props.title}`?

Code:

```
function testItems(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div className="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h1 className="card-title">{props.props.title}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default testItems
```

Did I miss something when reading about calling props?

I am calling testItems as a hit for algolia react-instantsearch:

```
const InfiniteHits = ( {hits, refineNext, hasMore} ) => {
  return(
    <div className="row">
      {hits.map((hit, index) => (
        <Hits props={hit} key={index} />
      ))}
      {hasMore &&
        <button className="ais-InfiniteHits-loadMore" onClick={refineNext}>Show more</button>
      }
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: How are you calling `testItems` component?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Hi, I added how I am calling it above

Comment: you need to pass props within an object like function testItems({props})

Comment: @MattBerg But isnt that just an object? Like I can do {props} or {whatever} and arent those the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what is happening is you are passing a prop into your component that is called `props`, which is an object that has a property called `props` (`{props: {title: "some title"}}`)

If you want to get it as `prop.title` you can just spread the properties like so

`<Hit {...hit}, key={index} />`

That will pass each key on `props` in as a prop.

Comment: Awesome! I didnt know you could use the spread operator like this. It doesnt like the comma but works perfectly without

Answer (score 3):

This is where the issue is

```
<Hits props={hit} key={index} />
```

You're supposed to pass it like this

```
<Hits hit={hit} key={index} />
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just make it `props.hit.title `? OP wanted to be able to `props.title`

Comment: The code snippet OP provided doesn't have 'title' in it. The issue over here was that OP is passing a prop into their child component as "props" and that is being set as a prop on the props that the child react component receives.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc is right that just changes the props in the console to hit and its `props.hit.title`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `props` as a prop in your component.
If you want to use props only one time or either want not to use it anymore. You can use destructuring in your testItems component like `function testItems({props})` or pass `title` and other props, if any, in your `Hit` component like `<Hit title={hit.title} key={index} />`.